# API: Get Flickr Photos by orientation

Tags: api, flickr

I'd like to get only landscape photos from Flickr but I don't see any parameters that lets me do that. Does anyone know if there's a way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the response from the [`flickr.photos.search`](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) feature, you can specify a number of optional parameters know as [`extras`](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html). For each URL (in format of `url_s,url_q`...) extra that you specify you'll get the following information.

**Sample JSON Reponse**

```
{
    ...
    "photos": { 
        "page": 1, 
        "pages": "478", 
        "perpage": 2, 
        "total": "4775", 
        "photo": [
            { 
                ...
                "longitude": 0, "accuracy": 0, "context": 0, "media": "photo",
                "media_status": "ready",
                "url_q": "https:\/\/farm4.staticflickr.com\/0000\/000_000_q.jpg",
                "height_q": "150",
                "width_q": "150",
                ...
            },
            { 
                ...
                "longitude": 0, "accuracy": 0, "context": 0, "media": "photo",
                "media_status": "ready",
                "url_q": "https:\/\/farm4.staticflickr.com\/0000\/000_111_q.jpg",
                "height_q": "150",
                "width_q": "150",
                ...
            },
        ] }, 
        "stat": "ok" 
};
```

If you want the URL for the Q sized photo, you will have the `height_q` and `width_q` attributes. If `width_q` is greater than `height_q` the orientation is **landscape**. If it's the opposite the orientation of the photo is **portrait**, otherwise it's a perfect square.

In Javascript you could write a function like this:

```
function determinePhotoOrientation(width, height) {
    if (width > height) {
        return 'landscape';
    } else if (width < height) {
        return 'portrait';
    }
    return 'square';
}
```

If you are using a different language you can make a similar function in that language to help you determine the orientation.

Comment: Using url_q (or url_s) won't work since they will always return a square image (i.e. the width and height returned will be the same). Use any of the other sizes instead, e.g. _t.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to get results that are only either 'portrait' or 'landscape'. I was going to use the technique described by @Dodzi (though not on the q image), but due to how my code is structured, I discovered what appears to be a hidden parameter for the flickr.photos.search endpoint.

Passing these parameters to the endpoint results, for me, in only photos being returned that match the orientation:

```
Array
(
    [per_page] => 100
    [extras] => url_sq,url_t,url_s,url_q,url_m,url_n,url_z,url_c,url_l,url_k,url_h,url_o,path_alias,owner_name,license
    [tag_mode] => all
    [tags] => 
    [license] => 1,2,3,4,5
    [sort] => interestingness-desc
    [orientation] => portrait
)
```

This also works, for me, when using 'landscape' as orientation.

Comment: Bummer. The orientation parameter now no longer works for me :(